# Get Salesforce Custom Field Value

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

I'm trying to get the value of a custom field in salesforce.  I'm trying to use this sample code:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Query_Sample_(Enterprise)

And add the custom field name to the select.  The select works, however, my output does not contain the custom field (only the other fields in my select).

```
$response = $client->query(SELECT Id,Name, Custom_field__c from Account limit 5);
```

I've also tried using the retrieve() method instead of query() but that is giving me the same problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.. it was sort of embarrassingly simple but here it is (maybe it will save someone else a couple of hours one day):

I needed to get a new wsdl out of the account.. if the wsdl doesn't have the fields you don't see them in your response.

Comment: Thanks! This did point me in the right direction - my WSDLs were out of date. However, I am still facing issues. I checked that the WSDLs contain the custom fields, and the WSDLs themselves are readable. No luck though. Is there anything obvious I missed?

Answer (score 2):

Does the user you're connecting as have permission to see that field?  Depending on your edition of Salesforce you will either have to add it to the page layout (Professional Edition) or add it to their profile.

I would use [ForceExplorer](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/ForceExplorer) to issue the SOQL statement and verify all permissions etc are working first.

Comment: I'm using a system administrator user, and I've verified the account has read permission on the field.  I've spent time on the phone with Salesforce support and they don't seem to know what is going on either.  I'll try ForceExplorer though, thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Also you need to disable WSDL cache by

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');
```

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS.  THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM.  I LOVE YOU.